# How I share my Dashboard with Other on Free version of Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, dashboard, kpi

I have a dashboard and i want to share with others. So I go to

File => Publish to Web

But i gives me an error "Contact Your admin" . So i go to "Admin Portal" and trying to enable the option "

"Allow existing and new codes"

But Admin Portal does not show me any thing.

[image]

On the other hand, I have shared another dashboard and it was successfully shared.

What should i do ?

Comment: As it clearly says, you should contact your admin to [allow you to generate new embed codes](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-publish-to-web-default-is-changing-and-it-affects-who-can-create-public-embed-codes/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andrey
I am the admin and I have shared another dashboard which was successfully shared.

Comment: Administrators see a lot more sections in the admin portal, like [Tenant settings](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/tenantSettings?noSignUpCheck=1), where in `Export and sharing settings` you can enable generation of **new** embed codes (https://powerbiblogscdn.azureedge.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/publish_to_web_admin_portal.png). The one you've successfully published has been already published (already had an embed code generated).

Comment: But i have not enabled "Allow existing and new codes" option before(Previously Shared Dashboard). 

and I am the only user that used the power bi desktop and web right now.

Comment: Did you [claimed admin rights over your tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/become-the-admin?view=o365-worldwide)?

Comment: Yes. (Based on other shared dashboard)
Now I want to know, why I am unable to see the "Tenant" option at Admin Portal.
IF this is a Admin Right issue ?
How i can solve it.